# How to handle partials in an scss project?

Tags: ruby, sass

Following problem: On my server I got a style.scss file in the main directory - I used `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed` and so everytime style.scss gets edited a new style.css will be created. What do I have to do that a new style.css will be created after editing a 'partial' in the sub directories?

**Edit:**
folder structure: 
my_theme_main_directory with style.scss and style.css
partials in my_theme_main_directory/css/globals

what I tried: 
command in main directory: --watch css/globals:css/globals
and also in the partials directory: --watch _layout.scss:layout.css --style compressed
but no new style.css was created

I deleted style.css and used again:
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed

Finally the changes were in the style.css but i want to get the style.css generated automatically when a partial gets edited.

Comment: Try: `sass --watch <sass_folder>:<css_folder>`

Comment: thx. But I already tried and it didn't help. Even with sass --watch _my_partial.scss:my_partial.css --style compressed it didn't work. A css is created but the content of the main style.css didn't change...

Comment: Could you update your question with your sass folder structure from the folder you're running the command above together with command you're running?

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to do this is to separate sass files form compiled css files. In your `my_theme_main_folder` create folder `sass` and move all the scss files to it, including partials (you can structure them as you like).

Then run from the level of `my_theme_main_folder`:

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

It will watch the whole `my_theme_main_folder/sass` folder and compile everything to `my_theme_main_folder/css` folder on any change in the first folder.

Comment: thx! But that would make things complicated for me. Because I got a directory globals and a directory mobile with same filenames and diffrent contents and I would have to rearrange my added scripts in Wordpress. So thanks for your help but I don't want to change my folder structure so I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have the right idea, you have to have something watch your Sass files if they update so it knows to build it out. [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) and [Gulp](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) both have things that automate that for you.

Here's an example

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'CSS complete' }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

This depends on how you architect your Sass build structure though. So in the above example, we look in the folder `/sass/` and compile out all the partials. I would read You can also take a look at [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) if you have the chance.

You can try using scaffolding tools like [Sassy Sass](https://github.com/ryanburgess/sassysass) to make it easy if you're too lazy to organize it yourself though.